# Map sql out parameter to POGO

Tags: jdbc, groovy

I have groovy code like the following

```
query.call(sqlString, [Sql.out(OracleTypes.CURSOR)]) { ResultSet cursor ->
        while (cursor.next()) {
            println cursor.getString("whatever")
        }
```

But what I want to be able to do, is to load the whole row into an object. Like in this example

```
sql.eachRow("Select * from Person") {
    persons << new Person( it.toRowResult() )
}
```

How can I get from one to the other, given that I have to work through an Oracle Out parameter?

Comment: Instead of using `query.call` use `query.callWithRows` (with an empty Closure argument `{}`) then use the regular `List.each` method on the resulting list. See the docs here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html#callWithRows(java.lang.String,%20List<Object>,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: @BalRog's suggestion will iterate the results twice. You can apply the desired mapping transformation on the closure itself

Comment: `callWithRows` produces a list of `Map`s (`GroovyRowResult` implements `Map`). So @Steve can use a Groovy map constructor, to go directly from the list of maps to a list of `Person`s. Anything else requires you to use `ResultSet.get<data-type> ` for each column to construct the desired map so that he can use the Groovy map constructor. Very crufty. If the efficiency is that important, use Java 8 streams on the `callWithRows` result list. That way you only produce one final list, the list of `Person`s.